# Multiple constructors in a class. Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

So this is what they are asking me to do:
1) Create a class called Person with the following conditions.
Attributes: name, age, DNI, sex (M for male, F for female), weight and height.
Every attribute, except DNI, will have default values according to its type (0 for numbers, empty string for String, etc..). Sex will be male by default.

2) Create the following constructors:
•   A constructor with default values.
•   A constructor with name, age and sex as parameters (other values by default).
•   A constructor with all attributes received as parameters.

I need to know the correct way to do this, to be able to create 3 objects of the class with different values.

```
class Person {
constructor(name, age, sex, dni, weight, height){
    this.name = '';
    this.age = 0;
    this.sex = 'M';
    this.dni = createDni();
    this.weight = 0;
    this.height = 0;
}

static Person1(name, age, sex){
    return new Person(name,age,sex);
}

static Person2(name, age, sex, dni, weight, height){
    return new Person(name, age, sex, dni, weight, height);
}
}

var Person1 = new Person(){
this.name = 'Manuel'
this.age = 25;
this.sex = 'M';
this.height = 1,75;
this.weight = 90;
}
```

I should be able to pass different values to 3 different objects created from the "Class".

Comment: That task is impossible. A class can only have one `constructor`.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Javascript and not Java assignment?

Comment: They gave me this exercise to get an interview for a job, and the files were all called "test JS" so i have to assume it's Javascript. There's no way this complicated answers are what they want, when something similar can be done much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's `class` syntax creates a single constructor function and an associated prototype object. There is no built-in overloading of functions, including constructor functions, in JavaScript. The only way to do "overloading" in JavaScript is to handle it within the code of the one function itself.

In your case, you have a couple of choices, but the simplest would probably be to simply use default parameter values on all of the parameters:

```
constructor(name = '', age = 0, sex = 'M', dni = createDni(), weight = 0, height = 0) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
}
```

Don't worry, `createDni` is only called if no argument is provided for `dni` when the constructor is called (or if the value provided is `undefined`).

One advantage to this is that the caller can supply arguments for none of the parameters, for all of them, or for anything in-between, not just 0, 3, and 6.

Live Example:

```js
function createDni() {
    console.log("createDni was called");
    return 42;
}
class Person {
    constructor(name = '', age = 0, sex = 'M', dni = createDni(), weight = 0, height = 0) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
console.log("No arguments:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Person()));
console.log("Three arguments:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Person("Joe Bloggs", 42, "M")));
console.log("Six arguments:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Person("Joe Bloggs", 42, "M", 67, 182, 6)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% important;
}
```

If you really wanted to only allow no arguments, three arguments, or six arguments, you could use a rest parameter or the `arguments` object. Using `arguments` would look like this:

```
constructor(name = '', age = 0, sex = 'M', dni = createDni(), weight = 0, height = 0) {
    const alen = arguments.length;
    if (alen !== 0 && alen !== 3 && alen !== 6) {
        throw new Error("0, 3, or 6 arguments are required");
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
}
```

Using a rest parameter looks like this, note that you lose the named parameters:

```
constructor(...args) {
    const alen = args.length;
    if (alen !== 0 && alen !== 3 && alen !== 6) {
        throw new Error("0, 3, or 6 arguments are required");
    }
    [
        this.name = "",
        this.age = 0,
        this.sex = "M",
        this.dni = createDni(),
        this.weight = 0,
        this.height = 0
    ] = args;
}
```

...where, again, `createDni` is only called when needed.

Comment: There's some confusion in your last two examples.  Both ignore `args`, and the penultimate one doesn't define the `name`, `age`, etc. variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel like the first example is the way to go. Although it doesn't solve the three constructors they ask for.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Thanks! Stoopid editing error, I've fixed it.

Comment: @ManuelSilva - Because you can't do that in JavaScript. :-) Yes, the first way is the way I'd use, barring a really good reason to require specific numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can only have one constructor, and the same as you have started I use static methods as named constructors, so I would write this class as follows:

```
class Contract {
    static notNull(value, message) { if(!value) throw new Error(message);  }
    static isArray(value, message) { if(!Array.isArray(value)) throw new Error(message);  }
    static isTrue(value, message)  { if(!value) throw new Error(message);  }
}

class Person {
    constructor (dni, name = "", age = 0, sex='M', width=0, height=0) {
        Contract.notNull(dni, "Parameter dni not specified");
        //check other parameters as well 
        this.dni = dni;
        this.name = name; // etc.
    }

    static fromArray(values) {
        Contract.isArray(values, "Parameter values must be array");
        Contract.isTrue(values.length === 6, "Expected 6 elements in array");
        return new Person(...values);
    }

    static fromNameAgeAndSex(name, age, sex) {
          return new Person(createDni(), name, age, sex);
    }
}
```